# Взаимодействие конструктора (или оператора) перемещения с константным объектом

Tags: c++, c++11

Кто хорошо знает Стандарт С++, прошу разъяснить ситуацию.

Среди правил хорошего тона (в том числе, описанных у С. Майерса в его "55 советах...") есть такое: арифметический оператор должен возвращать константный объект:

```
const TObject operator + (const TObject &a, const TObject &b);
```

Это делается, например, для того, чтобы нельзя было написать `(a+b)=c` или ещё как-то *испортить* полученный результат по дороге к его месту назначения.

Теперь, когда появились конструкторы и операторы перемещения, благодаря ним можно избежать лишнего копирования при таких действиях как

```
TObject c(a+b);
c = a+b;
```

Но будет ли вызван конструктор и оператор перемещения в этом случае? Ведь оператор `+` возвращает константный объект, его нельзя изменить (в том числе переместить)! Потому что перемещение предполагает, что я что-то меняю внутри объекта (например, обнуляю указатели на выделенную память, чтобы деструктор временного экземпляра не удалил память, отданную экземпляру `c`). Часто оператор перемещения реализуется вызовом `swap`, который также меняет оба объекта - левый и правый... но правый объект - константная ссылка.

Я заблуждаюсь или нет? Если нет, то как быть с описанным правилом хорошего тона, когда возвращать нужно константный объект?

Comment: Ну, насколько я понимаю, написать явный `TObject c(std::move(a+b));` можно даже в этом случае...

Comment: Что означает символ T в TObject ?

Comment: @ Vladimir Gamalian, это старая традиция названия классов начинать с `Т`. В Borland C++ Builder именно так и назывались объекты, по крайней мере, в начале 00-х годов, когда я на нём что-то писал.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не будет вызван конструктор перемещения, но будет вызван конструктор копирования. Не будет, потому что перемещающий конструктор **обычно** выглядит как `T&&` и никакого другого конструктора по умолчанию не будет.

Конечно, можно определить свой перемещающий конструктор вида `const T&&`, но что с ним делать? Он бесполезен, т.к. отличаться от копирующего конструктора он не будет ничем.

P.S. Это «правило» было сомнительно раньше, а стало ещё и вредным сейчас.

---

Кстати, в C++11 появилось и то, что позволяет явно выразить своё нежелание применения определённых функций к определённому типу аргументов. Так, к примеру, Ваш пример на присваивание можно запретить очень просто:
либо определить соответствующий `operator=` только для lvalue:

```
TObject& operator=(const TObject& rhs) &
{
    //...
    return *this;
}
```

Либо же запретить этот оператор для rvalue явно(предпочтительно):

```
TObject& operator=(const TObject& rhs) && = delete;
```

И всё, никаких правил не нужно выдумывать — Вы контролируете метод использования Вашего класса полностью.

Comment: Присмотрелся, и в ответе всё-таки `const` есть :)

Answer (score 3):

Здесь имеет место компромисс между эффективностью, с одной стороны, и простотой реализации и интуитивно понятной логикой, с другой стороны.

Естественно, когда мы получаем временный объект после выполнения оператора `operator +`, то достаточно логично выглядит, что вы не можете изменять это временное выражение, как в вашем примере

```
( a + b ) = c;
```

потому что это нарушает наше представление о подобных операциях вида

```
( 5 + 2 ) = 10;
```

С другой стороны если возвращается константный объект, то иметь с ним дело через константную `rvalue` ссылку, большого смысла не имеет, так как вы не сможете изменить состояние объекта, а следовательно все плюсы от возвращения `rvalue` ссылки теряются.

Поэтому если класс определен так, что объекты этого класса содержат много ресурсов, которые нужно освобождать при удалении объекта этого класса или, напротив, нужно создавать при создании объекта этого класса, то желательно определить оператор `operator +` так, чтобы он возвращал не константный временный объект, и можно было бы к этому объекту эффективно применять перемещающий конструктор или перемещающий оператор присваивания.

Именно таким образом объявлен `operator +` для стандартного класса `std::basic_string`, то есть он не возвращает константный временный объект из оператора.

Однако если вы хотите иметь дело с `rvalue` ссылками, то это делает код более запутанным.

Обратите внимание, что речь может идти не только о возвращаемом типе оператора, но также и о типах параметров этого оператора. Поэтому, имея дело с `rvalue`ссылками, вам придется иметь несколько перегрузок оператора.

Например,

```
TObject operator + ( const TObject &a, const TObject &b );
TObject operator + ( const TObject &a, TObject &&b );
TObject operator + ( TObject &&a, const TObject &b );
TObject operator + ( TObject &&a, TObject &&b );
```

Именно столько перегрузок этого оператора имеется для класса `std::basiс_string`, когда оба операнда относятся к объектам этого класса.

Когда же вы не имеете дело с `rvalue` ссылками, то вам достаточно объявить лишь одну перегрузку оператора

```
const TObject operator + ( const TObject &a, const TObject &b );
```

Поэтому для простых классов, объекты которых не являются ресурсо-затратными, этот оператор так и следует определять. В противном случае вам придется делать несколько перегрузок этого оператора.

Этот вопрос на самом деле достаточно серьезный, так как в настоящий момент в стандарте C++ имеется дефект относительно таких стандартных функций как `std::min`, `std::max` и `std::minmax`, которые работают только с константными ссылками, когда эти функции имеют дело с двумя аргументами. Я уже обратил внимание комитета по стандартизации C++, что эти функции следует переписать так, чтобы они могли иметь дело с не константными ссылками и, в частности, с `rvalue` ссылками в слзданной мною теме [Overloading std::min, std::max, and std::minmax for non-constant references](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/tnx2SaxEpYE).

Comment: Разве приведение `TObject &&b` к `const TObject &b` требует дополнительных операций?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вопрос касается не приведения типов, а эффективности работы с временными объектами. Если оператор возвращает временный объект, то когда он используется в другом вызове, то желательно с ним иметь дело через rvalue ссылку. Например, результат оператора operator + в свою очередь может быть операндом этого же оператора.

Comment: Я имел в виду min и max. Но, кажется, понял. Они должны вернуть `&&`, чтобы в последующем выражении его можно было использовать надлежащим образом. Об этом речь?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я привел в своем ответе ссылку на этот вопрос, где, в частности, также затрагиваются и rvalue ссылки.

Comment: Интересная у Вас логика, т.е. лучше не иметь вообще оптимизации, чем иметь хотя бы одну? Подход «всё или ничего» явно не для подобных случаев.

Comment: @ixSci Когда в дизайне происходит остановка на полпути, то это всегда воспринимается как дефект, или, по крайней мере, вызывает вопросы.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, вовсе нет. Как раз вопросы вызывает наличие оператора, который возвращает `const Obj` в современно C++, тем более, что другие перегрузки нужны лишь тогда, когда имеет место массовое применение оператора в одном выражении. А это может быть далеко не самый распространенный случай для ряда объектов. Поэтому, написание такого количества перегрузок может быть просто неоправдано. С другой стороны, такие вещи пишутся один раз, а потом используются во всех типах  как mix-inы, по типу boost::operators, так что никакой проблемы иметь все перегрузки нет.

Comment: @ixSci Всегда возникают вопросы, когда в одном месте вы работаете с rvalue ссылками, а в другом месте их полностью игнорируете, хотя никаких причин для этого нет. Если вы решили сделать оптимизацию по rvalue ссылкам, то что это за оптимизация, если эти ссылки игнорируются? Поэтому естественно те, кто будет читать такой  не последовательный код с логической точки зрения будут рассматривать это как недоработку.